Using generic SVG Icon color in scm/header
in my extension there are some svg icons. Until now for a command two different files need to be referenced for the dark or light theme.
{
"command": "extension.myCommand",
"title": "Do someting",
"category": "myExtension",
"icon": {
  "light": "./Assets/icons/light/check-all.svg",
  "dark": "./Assets/icons/dark/check-all.svg"
}

In the svg file there is an fill attribute to set the color.
My question: Is it possible to use the vscode css variables in that svg file to get the right color depending on the global theme?
I already tried to insert a style tag into the svg node like:
<svg>
<style>
  path {
    fill: var(--vscode-icon-foreground);
  }
</style>
<path ...>
</svg>

But that did not work. Using a normal color like red instead of the var did work.

with the developer tools you can see which CSS stuff is defined at the location of the SVG

Thank you for that hint. With that I discovered that there is a way to use the codicons with the $(iconname) syntax in the package.json. So I do not need to have the svg files stored in my extension.
